# Is there a way to get a class by name?

Tags: objective-c, string, class, dynamic-linking

In Objective-C, is there a way to get a class and send messages to it when you have the name of the class as a string? For example, is there a function `func` where `func(@"NSString") == [NSString class]`?

The reason that I want to know this is I am building a dynamic linker library for a language I am working on, and I want it to have an interface to Objective-C libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes — two, in fact. If you have a Foundation-type framework (e.g. from Cocoa, Cocoa Touch or GNUstep), you can use the [`NSClassFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring?language=occ) function, which is precisely the same as your `func`. If you do not want to depend on a framework, there's a similar runtime function, [`objc_getClass()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418952-objc_getclass?language=objc), that takes a `const char*` and returns the named class (or `nil` if none is found).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSClassFromString(NSString className)` to get the class object from its name.

Hope this helps!